# How to call component function from parent component and change it state to render child component in React

Tags: reactjs

I have problem with passing state from parent component. I'm trying to call function in my ParentComponent in onClick from my ChildComponent to render ChildComponent in ParentComponent. I'm new in React Library and I'm really don't know how I can achive this.
I've tried something like that.

ParentComponent:

```
import React from 'react'
import {ChildComponent, showDialog} from './childComponent'

const ParentComponent = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <button type='button' onClick={() => showDialog()}>
        </div>
    )
}

export default ParentComponent
```

ChildComponent:

```
import {React, useState} from 'react'

const {isOpened, setIsOpened} = useState(false)

function showDialog() {
    setIsOpened(true)
}

function ChildComponent() {
    if (isOpened) {
        return (
            <dialog open></dialog>
        )
    }
}

export {ChildComponent, showDialog}
```

Comment: This is called lifting state up, check the docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html Note, the docs are using class components, but the same applies to functional components

Comment: @Val here is the [beta version docs](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/managing-state) which has examples for function components

Comment: @KcH How I can use this when I have only button in my parent component which activating render child component in parent. I know how to pass data between components. I want to have function which renders child component in child component I just want to call it from parent component.

Comment: sorry i didn't understood it tbh

Answer (score 0):

You should be passing the activation function as a prop to the child component. Then using the function on click in the child.